# Getting the uri of the file passed to the program and copying it

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I'm trying to get the uri of a file from the intent when the program is launched from the explorer by passing the selected file into it. For further copying of this file and processing.

To make an application appear in the "Send to" list of a selected file using File Explorer
the manifest says:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When launching the activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
 
    // uri is always 0
 
    if(uri != null){
     InputStream fileStream = null;
     fileStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
     //
    }
 }
}
```

Why is uri always always null? Below I figured out what is in the intent at different launches.

During the standard launch of the program, the following information appears in the intent:

`Intent { act = android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]flg=0x10200000 cmp=ru.mysoft/.SplashActivity bnds=[540,370][804,656] }`

When starting the program when transferring a file to it through the explorer in the intent:

`Intent { act = android.intent.action.SEND typ=*/* flg=0x1b0800001 cmp=ru.mysoft/.SplashActivity clip={*/* U:content://media/external/file/77191} (has extras) }`

What information from the intent should be in the uri to create a stream for the passed file to my application?

I have tried creating a thread like this:

```
 String sourceFilename = "//media/external/file/77191";
 BufferedInputStream bis = null;
 bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
```

But:
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/external/file/77191 (No such file or directory)

Comment: getIntent().getClipData()

Answer (score 0):

> Why is uri always always null?

Because that is not where you get the `Uri` for `ACTION_SEND`. Look in `EXTRA_STREAM` for the `Uri`.

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#handling-content) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (uri != null) {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                String path = null;
 
                ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                Cursor metaCursor = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (metaCursor != null) {
                    try {
                        if (metaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            path = metaCursor.getString(0);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        metaCursor.close();
                    }
 
                    Toast messg_err = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    messg_err.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    messg_err.show();
                }
 
// then copy the resulting archive using path
```